# Where is the SQL Server 2012 formula stored?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am doing a report, and one of the tables called `tblProduct` has a calculation triggered in SQL Server that calculates cost on a column. I am having trouble locating the formula. Is there a way to determine what or where the formula is being pulled from ?

Comment: are you referring to a calculated column or a trigger on the table?

Comment: let's say both, how would I find out where it's located in sql server 2012?

Comment: What makes you so sure the calculation is "triggered" rather than populated as a typical database column?

Comment: @shawnt00 because it's calculating 5 year> cost and also another column 18months <

Comment: That's really not an answer to my question but try searching `syscomments`. The code isn't necessarily in the database though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the sounds of it you are looking for a calculated column. So if you are looking for the logic within a calculated column you can get this by simply doing the folowing:

1. Right click on the table
2. Go to script table as
3. Click on CREATE to.

Within the definition then you should see the calculated column definition

SO in the below example:

```
USE [KamTest]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[temp]    Script Date: 2/8/2016 2:24:40 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temp](
    [Col1] [int] NULL,
    [Col2] [int] NULL,
    [col3]  AS ([Col1]*[Col2])  --<-- the calculated column
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

below is the calculated column definition

```
[col3]  AS ([Col1]*[Col2])
```

Comment: i only see [Cost] [money] NULL

Comment: can you post you complete table definition if possible?

Comment: is it ok if I message it to you ?

Comment: sure you can message me

Comment: is it possible to message on stackover flow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102931/discussion-between-kamran-farzami-and-aluminum-starch).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Management Studio in the object explorer go to:

```
YourDB>YourTable>Triggers>YourTrigger
```

Comment: I went to the tblProduct table, I expanded the trigger field, it wasn't there

Comment: Are you using a stored procedure to retrieve data from the specified table?

Comment: Well, the calculation is already there in the specified table(a person created this 15 years ago). On the specified table,  the column is called Cost and it calculates cost in the past 5 years.

Comment: @aluminum_starch it sounds like a calculated column to me. Seeing that there are no triggers. See my answer it may help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out , it maybe for someone in the future. It was in the server agent under Jobs and there were jobs that calculated another sp.